# Problem with string and switch-statement ?? C++ Grading system

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, switch-statement

When I started to make this code I encountered problem with string and switch statement that's why I am not sure that I bypassed this problem correctly. And the main problem is that program print answers only for chart but not for  string determinations. Maybe that's because use wrong ''If".
Here is my code :

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string> 
>
> using std::cin;
> using std::cout;
> using std::string;
> using namespace std;
>
>  constexpr long long string_hash(const char *s) {
> long long hash{}, c{};
> for (auto p = s; *p; ++p, ++c) {
>     hash += *p << c;
> }
> return hash; }   constexpr long long operator"" _sh(const char *s, size_t) {
> return string_hash(s); }
>
> int main() {
>     cout << "Ievadiet atzimi ar burtiem (A, B, C, D, F) ==> ";
>     string atzime;
>     char burts;
>     double atzime_sk, pluss, minuss;
>
>     cin >> atzime;
>     burts = atzime[0];
>     switch(burts) 
>     {
>     case 'A':
>         atzime_sk = 4;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>     case 'B':
>         atzime_sk = 3;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>     case 'C':
>         atzime_sk = 2;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>     case 'D':
>         atzime_sk = 1;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>     case 'F':
>         atzime_sk = 0;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
>     
>    if (atzime[1] == '-' || '+')
>     {
>       switch (string_hash(atzime.c_str()))
>       {
>       case "+"_sh:
>         pluss = atzime_sk + 0.3;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>       case "-"_sh:
>         minuss = atzime_sk - 0.3;
>         cout << "Tava atzime ir ==> " << atzime_sk;
>         break;
>       default:
>         break;
>       }
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:c]? This is _not_ C.

Comment: `if (atzime[1] == '-' || '+')` won't do what you expect - that needs to be `if (atzime[1] == '-' || atzime[1] == '+')`. And how did you not get a diagnostic on `case "+"_sh:`?

Comment: The `default` cases do nothing with `atzime_sk`, `pluss` or `minuss` which remain uninitialised.

Comment: What kind of problem? If it's a compilation error, copy compiler messages to the question. If it's undesired output, post it along with expected output.

Comment: FYI, the `case` statement only works with integers.  Single characters are essentially integers.  The `case` statement doesn't work with strings.

Comment: What is this funky syntax: `"-"_sh`?  What do you want it to do / represent?

Comment: The main problem is that If I write in console ''A'' program gave me correct answer 4, but when I try to write ''A+'' it do noting and print just 4.

Comment: with ''_sh" as you can see I use ''constexpr'' that's because I can not use string with switch.

Comment: @Alex Did you read the duplicate question? If so, do you understand why `if (atzime[1] == '-' || '+')` is always `true`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (atzime[1] == '-' || '+')
```

That does not do what you think it does.

`((atzime[1]=='-') || '+')`  so if the first test fails, the second test is just `'+'` by itself which is `true`.  So it's always `true`.

You need to write that as:  `(atzime[1] == '-' || atzime[1] == '+')`

Meanwhile, I don't think your subsequent `switch` statement will ever match anything.  You seem to be expecting a string that begins with a letter and then a `+` or `-`.  So if you type, for example `"A+"` the hash will not match either that of `"+"` nor `"-"` by itself.

Comment: If the answer is supposed to provide some sort of help you could break it down and explain what it really does and show how to do what OP intended to do.